# RabbitMQ creates a number of strange processes

Tags: rabbitmq

I happened to find a number of strange processes created by rabbitmq on my RabbitMQ server. I ran rabbitmq server in a docker container. I recreated the container and hours later those processes appeared again. There're some consumers connecting to it. Any idea about what those processes for? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I found every time I ran "rabbitmqctl list_connections", more "[inet_gethost] <defunct>" will be created.